# Can a prize "increase"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, collocations

I have a mobile app that runs tournaments with cash prizes.

I want to add a sentence which I'm not sure it's correct grammatically:

> The prize increases every time one of your friends join.

Can a prize "increase"? Is there maybe any better way to say this?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely no problem in *increasing prizes.* In fact, the use is pretty common. Say, for example, [a lottery prize can *increase*](https://inshorts.com/en/news/lottery-prize-increases-to-%E2%82%B92800-crore-after-no-one-wins-it-1514875191146) in certain cases.

You can find hundreds of instances where *prize gets increased* in terms of money or something else. Just one little concern though - everywhere, the increased amount would be somehow mentioned.

Here, in your case, the *prize* would serve as a *reward* that would increase every time users' friends join the game.